# sql server xp_cmdshell echo NVARCHAR(MAX) string

Tags: sql, sql-server, varchar, xp-cmdshell

I'm trying to use `master.sys.xp_cmdshell` to echo a extremely large string.  I believe the max of `varchar` which I think is something around 8000 characters is too small so I'm not sure how to accomplish this because xp_cmdshell expects the string to be varchar.

My `@MESSAGE` variable is declared as `NVARCHAR(MAX)` and I need every bit of it. Here is my code:

```
DECLARE @EXECUTION_STRING NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'ECHO ' + @MESSAGE + ' > "' + @FULL_PATH + '\' + @FILE_NAME + '"'
EXEC master.sys.xp_cmdshell @EXECUTION_STRING
```

So, my question is; how can I accomplish a string to file write when the string is of type `NVARCHAR(MAX)`?

---

New plan, based on @Arun's suggestion of creating an SP with the BCP functionality.  Here is my code so far:

```
DECLARE @THCIC_OUTPUT_TABLE             VARCHAR(255) = '##temp' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), CONVERT(INT, RAND() * 1000000))
DECLARE @RESULT                         INTEGER
DECLARE @THCIC_OUTPUT_EXECUTION_COMMAND NVARCHAR(MAX) = ' 
                                                        CREATE TABLE [' + @THCIC_OUTPUT_TABLE + '] ( CONTENT NVARCHAR(MAX) )

                                                        INSERT INTO [' + @THCIC_OUTPUT_TABLE + ']
                                                            SELECT @MESSAGE
                                                      '

EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @THCIC_OUTPUT_EXECUTION_COMMAND, N'@MESSAGE NVARCHAR(MAX)', @MESSAGE

DECLARE @THCIC_OUTPUT_FILE_WRITE_COMMAND VARCHAR(1000) = '
                                                          BCP ”SELECT CONTENT FROM [' + @THCIC_OUTPUT_TABLE + ']"
                                                          QUERYOUT "' + @FULL_PATH + '\' + @FILE_NAME + '" -w -T -S ' + @@servername 

PRINT @THCIC_OUTPUT_FILE_WRITE_COMMAND

EXECUTE @RESULT = master.sys.xp_cmdshell @THCIC_OUTPUT_FILE_WRITE_COMMAND, NO_OUTPUT
PRINT @RESULT
EXECUTE ( 'DROP TABLE [' + @THCIC_OUTPUT_TABLE + ']' )
```

So, the frustrating part is that I'm receiving an error, yet my file is not being written.  The output of `PRINT @THCIC_OUTPUT_FILE_WRITE_COMMAND` is:

```
BCP ”SELECT CONTENT FROM [##temp878274]"
QUERYOUT "\\TXPDC-FS01\Profiles\cofarmer\My Sandbox\THCIC\Q2_2014\Burleson\PIPSUB2938718184092014251607.txt" -w -T -S TXPDC-STKSQL01
```

While the output of `PRINT @RESULT` is: `1`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: short of using `substring` to cut it into bits, you'll probably be better off using CLR or OLE for this. Converting from nvarchar to varchar has data loss issues as well.

Comment: Read https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/reading-and-writing-files-in-sql-server-using-t-sql/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't on xp_cmdshell, because windows xp command line string limit is a little over 8,000 chars. Your better off making another stored procedure for bcp.

Comment: Ok, I'm wanting to export a text variable to a file though, not direct query results.  Can you provide some direction for where to find this particular functionality; either within bcp or something else?

Comment: @sadmicrowave You can try to use SQLCMD to export data into a file. Here is a link with some examples: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic667066-1365-1.aspx

Comment: using this idea I created a BCP statement, I also opened another question regarding problems with the statement, but this answer led me in the right direction.  Here is the link to the other post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26059604/sql-server-bcp-command-not-writing-nvarcharmax-variable-contents-to-file

Answer (score 2):

If you can cut the message into two halves then you can output the first one to a new file and then append the second half to that file.

```
DECLARE @EXECUTION_STRING1 NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'ECHO ' + @MESSAGE1 + ' > "' + @FULL_PATH + '\' + @FILE_NAME + '"'
DECLARE @EXECUTION_STRING2 NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'ECHO ' + @MESSAGE2 + ' >> "' + @FULL_PATH + '\' + @FILE_NAME + '"'
EXEC master.sys.xp_cmdshell @EXECUTION_STRING1
EXEC master.sys.xp_cmdshell @EXECUTION_STRING2
```

This will put a line break between the two halves which may or may not fit nicely with what you need to do depending on whether there is a natural place for a line break.

For more on Redirection
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb490982.aspx