# SQL Server BCP Command not Writing NVARCHAR(MAX) Variable Contents to File

Tags: sql-server, file-io, sql-server-2008-r2, bcp

I'm having issues with SQL Server's `BCP`. I'm not getting an error message but the command is also not writing anything to the path specified.

Here is my code:

In this scenario, the only variable not accounted for in the code below is `@MESSAGE` which is a `NVARCHAR(MAX)` and will take up most of that space so `VARCHAR(8000)` won't be nearly big enough.

```
DECLARE @OUTPUT_TABLE VARCHAR(255) = '##temp' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), CONVERT(INT, RAND() * 1000000))
DECLARE @RESULT INTEGER
DECLARE @OUTPUT_EXECUTION_COMMAND NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'CREATE TABLE [' + @OUTPUT_TABLE + '] ( CONTENT NVARCHAR(MAX) )

                                                    INSERT INTO [' + @OUTPUT_TABLE + ']
                                                        SELECT @MESSAGE'

EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @OUTPUT_EXECUTION_COMMAND, N'@MESSAGE NVARCHAR(MAX)', @MESSAGE

DECLARE @OUTPUT_FILE_WRITE_COMMAND VARCHAR(1000) = 'BCP ”SELECT CONTENT FROM [' + @OUTPUT_TABLE + ']"
                                                      QUERYOUT "' + @FULL_PATH + '\' + @FILE_NAME + '" -w -T -S ' + @@servername 

PRINT @OUTPUT_FILE_WRITE_COMMAND

EXECUTE @RESULT = master.sys.xp_cmdshell @OUTPUT_FILE_WRITE_COMMAND, NO_OUTPUT

PRINT @RESULT

EXECUTE ( 'DROP TABLE [' + @OUTPUT_TABLE + ']' )
```

So, the frustrating part is that I'm receiving an error, yet my file is not being written.

The output of `PRINT @OUTPUT_FILE_WRITE_COMMAND` is:

```
BCP ”SELECT CONTENT FROM [##temp878274]"
QUERYOUT "\\TXPDC-FS01\Profiles\cofarmer\My Sandbox\THCIC\Q2_2014\Burleson\PIPSUB2938718184092014251607.txt" -w -T -S TXPDC-STKSQL01
```

While the output of `PRINT @RESULT` is: `1`

Yet nothing is being written. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't find any thing wrong except this double quote (**”**) near `BCP ”SELECT CONTENT FROM....`. Can you replace it with (") and then try it again...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the issue is the line break in the`@OUTPUT_FILE_WRITE_COMMAND` (and the erroneous double quote`”`). Removing the line break worked for me:

```
DECLARE @OUTPUT_FILE_WRITE_COMMAND VARCHAR(1000) = 'BCP "SELECT CONTENT FROM [' + @OUTPUT_TABLE + ']" QUERYOUT "' + @FULL_PATH + '\' + @FILE_NAME + '" -w -T -S ' + @@servername
```

Result: 0 and the file was created.